# Making sense of Scala FP Libraries

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, cats-effect, zio

Just for the sake of quick clarity for someone who wants to start working with Scala FP library, on a journey to become better at pure FP.

Would someone clarify the difference/relation between Cats and Cats-Effect, Cats-Effects IO? On top of that, where does Zio, and Monix stand with respect to it? Finally, what would be the relation to ScalaZ 7/8?

So far based on what I have read, a good combination of the library to work with based on the documentation available and what they do would be Cats, then Cats-Effect, and ZIO which could be used with Cats-effects? But I can't quite understand well why and would like to set myself a good path to learn to be better FP programmer while remaining productive, and not having to finish "FP Programming in Scala" before I start making choices.

Comment: Check out https://kubuszok.com/2019/io-monad-which-why-and-how/

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Scalaz** started as an attempt to port to Scala some well-established abstractions from Haskell (like typeclasses for Monad, Functor and much more). Problem with it was, that it doesn't have great documentation, so basically, you needed to use documentation of Haskell libraries in order to understand how to use certain **Scalaz** resources.
Nowadays, you there's Sam Halliday’s *Functional Programming for Mortals* which you can use as a learning source for **Scalaz**.

**Cats** was created later, as essentially reimplementation what **Scalaz** provided. **Cats** has a lot better [documentation](https://typelevel.org/cats/) than **Scalaz**, there is also great book  *Scala with Cats*.

**Scalaz** and **Cats** might have very similar purposes, so they're competing as general purpose FP library for Scala. There are also libraries that serve as [compatibility-layer](https://github.com/djspiewak/shims) between both libraries.

**Cats-Effect** is a library, which provides *"standard"* *IO monad* for Scala (again idea borrowed from Haskell (?)). It depends on code from *Cats* core library.

You can read more [here](https://kubuszok.com/2019/io-monad-which-why-and-how/#shortcomings-of-future) why there is a need for *IO* monad for Scala, when there's standard's library *Future*.

**Monix** is another library, which provides an **IO monad** for Scala, but this time it's called `Task`. It was meant to be a more [high-level abstraction](https://monix.io/blog/2018/03/20/monix-vs-cats-effect.html) and provide easier interop with code using standard library *Future*. In reality, it shares a lot of code with **Cats-Effect** and creator of **Monix** [Alexandru Nedelcu](https://twitter.com/alexelcu) is also one of the main contributors of **Cats-Effect**.
[Here](https://monix.io/blog/2018/03/20/monix-vs-cats-effect.html) you may find more information about the differences between `cats.effect.IO` and `monix.eval.Task`, as well as some of the history of both.

Lastly, there is **ZIO** which started as an attempt to reimplement *IO monad* for *Scalaz*, but ended up as a completely separate library (so it does not depend on *Scalaz* codebase).

The great thing about all libraries is, they're all implementing typeclasses (like *Sync* or *Concurrent*) from *Cats-Effect*, so using pattern called *tagless final* you're able to switch between implementation.

That hierarchy of **typeclasses** also serve as an interpolation library between, many (all (?)) of the **IO** implementations (as by the time it was created there already were `fs2.Task`, `monix.Task` & `scalaz.IO`). Also, apparently, in a [future](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/issues/321) the **IO** part may be moved into another module, leaving only the interoperability **typeclasses**.

If you don't use *tagless final* you can still use modules that provide interop between certain *IO* monads, for example **zio-interop-cats** (between *ZIO* and *Cats-Effect* or **catnap** for *Monix*-*Cats-Effect*.

---

For your information, I recently extended this answer into a [full-fledged blog post](https://blog.softwaremill.com/figuring-out-scala-functional-programming-libraries-af8230efccb4).

Comment: Incredible answer thank i get it all. Could share some of those Lib that you refer to here: "If you don't use tagless final you can still use libraries that provide interop between certain IO monads." ???

Comment: For example there is module in zio: `zio-interop-cats` and for monix `monix-catnap`. I changed that paragraph to use word `modules` instead of `libraries` because it was misleading.